# Where can I download Nokia os?

Tags: mobile, nokia

I want to develop an application for Nokia mobiles. For that I need the Nokia OS and a suitable SDK

Where can I get these two, possibly with some sample applications to ease the learning?

Comment: Did you try searching for 'nokia' and 'sdk' here on stackoverflow? There seem to be some usefull pointers there! ( http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nokia+sdk )

Comment: If you have patience you can wait for the first Windows Phone driven Nokia's later this year. I'm very interested in seeing how that turns out.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like pretty much everything you would need to know - I know it's not a specific answer but it should provide a great starting place:

http://www.forum.nokia.com/

Answer (score 0):

Nokia phones use [Symbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbian) OS. Symbian is an open source OS, which was maintained by the Symbian.org.

Unfortunately, Symbian.org recently [converted to a licensing body](http://blog.symbian.org/2010/12/17/symbian-foundation-is-completing-its-transition-to-a-licensing-body/) only and stopped any further development on the OS, and as part of that the Symbian official website was shut down. The Symbian platform is still accessible over FTP, until March 31, 2011.

The further OS development will officially be driven and maintained by Nokia. You can read the latest news about this from Nokia official [Symbian blog](http://symbian.nokia.com/). You can find some samples and documentation about the platform at [Forum Nokia](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Develop/Other_Technologies/Symbian_C++/). There you can also find the latest Symbian SDK ([S^3 SDK](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/ec866fab-4b76-49f6-b5a5-af0631419e9c/S60_All_in_One_SDKs.html)), along with other Nokia-specific SDKs and libraries, like [S60 development library](http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-07F7CEA3-DC49-40E1-B313-5AAC1A5A3F8D_cover.html) and [Qt development library](http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Qt_for_Symbian_Developers_Library/GUID-97A34C6E-9F2B-4743-86F8-563362F7047A_cover.html).

Answer (score 0):

what you refer to as [Nokia OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_OS) in fact:

1. legally not available to 3rd party
2. not suitable for "normal" binary apps - it had been designed to *not* have installable applications in order to protect telco environment from malware and other risks on terminal side
3. you **can** develop at least for [S40](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Devices/Series_40/) but you don't need "Nokia OS" for that, all necessary tools are available there - it is common J2ME programming with (optionally) some Nokia *flavors*